# JQuery if hovering on either element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

So I have 2 divs. One is "top" and one is "menu." I got "menu" to fade in when you hover on "top" in JQuery, as shown:

```
$(".top").mouseover(function(){
    $(".menu").fadeIn(200);
});

$(".top").mouseout(function(){
    $(".menu").fadeOut(200);
});
```

But I want to make it so if I'm also hovering on "menu," "menu" will stay faded in. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will do it for you. It waits half a second before hiding the menu. If the user hovers over the menu in that time, then it cancels the hide operation.

```
var timer;

$(".top").mouseover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(".menu").fadeIn(200);
});

$(".top, .menu").mouseout(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".menu").fadeOut(200);
    }, 500);
});

$(".menu").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable that remembers if you are hovering on the menu:

```
var isHoveringMenu;

$(".menu").mouseover(function(){
    isHoveringMenu = true;
});

$(".menu").mouseout(function(){
    isHoveringMenu = false;
    $(".menu").fadeOut(200); // you probably want this here
});

$(".top").mouseover(function(){
    $(".menu").fadeIn(200);
    isHoveringMenu = true; // not necessary, but sounds good
});

$(".top").mouseout(function(){
    if (!isHoveringMenu) {
        $(".menu").fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

You may want to tweak this slightly -- the best solution depends on the spatial relationship between the two divs, so we 'd need to see the layout first.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you are assuming that the mouseover event will fire on ".menu" before the mouseout event fires on ".top". In my experience, this is not something you can depend on.